Flutter reverse engineering: how to change string to another shorter or longer string?
I'm translating a flutter app, and I don't have the source code. So I'm trying to modify the libapp.so to translate some UI text string, which hard coded in the dart code.
The translated string could be shorter or longer than the original string.
For example:
Here is the flutter demo app
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

I want change the text You have pushed the button this many times: to hello (which is shorter) or You have pushed the button this many times, hello: (which is longger). Now I don't have the source code. I want to achieve this by modify the libapp.so.

Is this achievable?
How to achieve this?
Thanks!


Using tool 010Editor.
When length of the new string  is equal to the older, just replace it.
When shorter, replace it with padding \0.
When longer, I don't know how to do yet.
